# conjure-up from snap raises _unspecified_spell error

Tags: conjure-up

I did:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
conjure-up
```

on physical server (Quad Core x 2 with 12GB-RAM and 146GB Hard, but find below last lines of my error log.

```
rvtadmin@u16:~$ cat .cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log
2017-04-18 14:21:07,376 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: AddRelation returned: {'endpoints': {'nova-cloud-controller': {'name': 'amqp', 'role': 'requirer', 'interface': 'rabbitmq', 'optional': False, 'limit': 1, 'scope': 'global'}, 'rabbitmq-server': {'name': 'amqp', 'role': 'provider', 'interface': 'rabbitmq', 'optional': False, 'limit': 0, 'scope': 'global'}}}
2017-04-18 15:01:50,051 [ERROR] log.py:17 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Failure in deploy done: Applications did not start successfully
2017-04-18 15:01:50,075 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Showing dialog for exception: Applications did not start successfully
```

Comment: What does `juju status` output give you? Also can you try the beta release? `sudo snap refresh conjure-up --beta`